# "SELECT id, title, @natusort:=@natusort + 1 AS ordercount" does not increment as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

My query in MySQL does not behave as expected.

```
SET @natusort := 0;

SELECT id, title,  @natusort:=@natusort + 1 AS ordercount
FROM categories
JOIN table1 ON id = table1.parentid
ORDER BY title LIMIT 10
```

I expected a set of results like this:

```
ID  title   ordercount
------------------------------------
67  aaa     1   
23  aab     2
65  aac     3
47  aad     4
78  aba     5
32  abc     6
43  abd     7
33  aca     8
46  acb     9
12  acd     10
```

But I got this set instead:

```
ID  title   ordercount
------------------------------------
67  aaa     12  
23  aab     3
65  aac     12
47  aad     34
78  aba     4
32  abc     36
43  abd     31
33  aca     15
46  acb     19
12  acd     50
```

How can I get the increment to work sequentially starting from 1 and follow the order by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What appears to be happening here is that first your sequence is being generated across the result set, and then you are limiting to 10 records based on some order.  What you're left with isn't necessarily a sequence from 1 to 10.  The best fix here might be to use `ROW_NUMBER`, if you are using MySQL 8+.  If you must stick with your current approach, then wrap in a subquery before generating the sequence:

```
SELECT id, title,  @natusort:=@natusort + 1 AS ordercount
FROM
(
    SELECT id, title
    FROM categories
    INNER JOIN table1 ON id = table1.parentid
    ORDER BY title
    LIMIT 10
) t
ORDER BY title;
```

For the `ROW_NUMBER` option, just change your select to:

```
SELECT id, title, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY title) AS ordercount
FROM categories
...
```

Comment: Thank you.It really works!! The ROW_NUMBER OVER (ORDER BY xxx) it works. Yes my MySQL is the latest version 8+. I don't know how efficient is my query and in conjunction with your solution but it works

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`, as in:

```
SELECT id, title,
  row_number() over(order by title) as ordercount
FROM categories
JOIN table1 ON id = table1.parentid
ORDER BY title 
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `row_number()` in MySQL 8+.

The issue you are having is that `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` are not compatible with variables in more recent versions of MySQL pre-8.0.  I don't remember exactly when this stopped working, but I have in mind `GROUP BY` stopped working in 5.6 and `ORDER BY` in 5.7.  I wish I could forget such trivia.

In any case, the solution is to order in a subquery:

```
SELECT tc.*, (@natusort := @natusort + 1) AS ordercount
FROM (SELECT id, title
      FROM categories c JOIN
           table1 t1
           ON c.id = t1.parentid
     ORDER BY title
    ) tc CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT @natusort := 0) params
ORDER BY title
LIMIT 10;
```

Note that I've included the initialization of `@natusort` in the same query, so only one statement is necessary.

Comment: Gordon, may I ask what is the point of using `ORDER BY` in the subquery aliased as `tc`, given that you just further order and limit on the outside?

Comment: @GordonLinoff. My friend Gordon ! Thanks so much for your reply.  MySQL 8+ is the only way to go. Older versions get me stuck ! I prefer row_number thing. Thanks

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. . . I thought I explained that.  The use of variables with `ORDER BY` doesn't work in MySQL 5.7 -- at least starting at some point.  MySQL needs to work off the sorted, materialized, derived table for it to work.  This is based on *when* the variables are evaluated -- and it switched from after the sort to before the sort.

Answer (score 0):

If using `SET @natusort := 0`at the beginning is not working then you can Initialize it using joins example :

```
SELECT id, title, (@natusort:=@natusort + 1) AS ordercount
FROM categories
JOIN table1 ON id = table1.parentid
inner join (SELECT @natusort := 0)
ORDER BY title LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This is identical to what the OP already has, and won't work.